# Поведение элемента label в Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, input, label

Во всех браузерах, если набрать что-нибудь в input, а потом кликнуть на связанный label, каретка устанавливается после последнего набранного символа, и только в Firefox выделяется всё содержимое inputа. Как выровнять поведение, желательно без использования javascript?

```
<label>Click me <input type="text" /></label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yn2u73j1/

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-user-focus

```css
label{
  -moz-user-focus: ignore;
}
```

```html
<label>Click me <input type="text" /></label>
```

Comment: Уже пробовал - помогает лишь частично, если убрать фокус с inputа, а потом кликнуть на label, опять всё выделяется.